# How do I get gopls to work in NeoVim with lspconfig?

Tags: go, neovim, gopls

gopls in neovim, using lspconfig, does not seem to be working with any go file, even one that has a .git or go.mod file. My lspconfig can be found below, and after that is a LspInfo in a .go file showing it should be working. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
lspconfig["gopls"].setup({
    capabilities = capabilities,
    on_attach = on_attach,
})
```

[image]

I've gone through almost every reddit post on this, and have tried messing with my go env, but nothing seems to be working. I've also looked a logs, and they do mention go_proxy=Off, but my go env says differently, which is weird.

Comment: Have you checked than your `gopls` binary execs correctly ? In your screenshot, we can see `pid: nil` for `gopls`.

Comment: @lcheylus how would I do that, and if it does not what would the fix be?

Comment: For example, check `gopls` version with command `gopls version` and print `gopls` API in JSON format with `gopls api-json`.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to specify the `filetypes`. Here is a sample configuration (that I currently use)

```
lspconfig.gopls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  capabilities = capabilities,
  cmd = {"gopls"},
  filetypes = { "go", "gomod", "gowork", "gotmpl" },
  root_dir = util.root_pattern("go.work", "go.mod", ".git"),
  settings = {
    gopls = {
      completeUnimported = true,
      usePlaceholders = true,
      analyses = {
        unusedparams = true,
      },
    },
  },
}
```